# How to get google dataflow running jobs in java using client library

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-client

I am trying to get all jobs from a project using Google client library for dataflow. I am able to fetch metrics using job Id. But unable to get all jobs inside a project, any code snippet will be very helpful. We can use Apache beam runner as well. There is a method list all jobs in Apache runner but I am unable to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use this API: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/list

This should have an example showing how to use the Java client: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/samples/dataflow-v1beta3-generated-JobsV1Beta3-ListJobs-sync.

Comment: Hi, I lost my access to posting questions with this question. I am not sure how this question is against stackoverflow guidelines. I have one more question here.

I have created a big query table of fields [array of struct](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated) now what is the best way to add multiple addresses for an already inserted record?

Comment: I think BigQuery is mostly always handled as append-only, and you can use MERGE statements if you want to join rows. Please take a look at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement